# How to implement Mouse Look in Java3d

Tags: java-3d

I'm at a loss here. I've got a simple terrain generation algorithm working, and I've got some simple keyboard navigation working by extending ViewPlatformAWTBehavior and handling my own events. That's all well and good, and I can follow terrain. Hooray!

What I'd like to do is get some simple "mouse look" working. MouseRotate is close, but I'm looking for something more like an FPS ... where you aren't going to roll the camera, you're limited to 90 degrees vertical (up or down), and the mouse cursor is captured by the JFrame (with an escape).

I just can't seem to get it to work. I can capture the mouse event just fine, and mouseMoved works. I could probably just use an invisible cursor, and that would get me a large part of the way there (maybe), but I'd be stuck when trying to keep the mouse in the screen ... as soon as you're out of the frame, the mouse would be visible and stop rotating the view.

I keep thinking I must be going about this wrong, because this has to be a fairly common implementation, but I can't find anything on it.

Does anyone have some pointers or references?

Comment: Ok ... for those looking for an answer to this, turns out I was just implementing Robot incorrectly. Robot works just fine for re-centering the mouse.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want this is the code to make a full screen window which will help you with mouse problems

```
package fullscreen;

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;   

public class FullScreen extends JFrame{

private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
private JButton fullscreenButton = new JButton("Fullscreen Mode");
private boolean Am_I_In_FullScreen = false;
private int PrevX,PrevY,PrevWidth,PrevHeight;

public static void main(String[] args) {
     FullScreen frame = new FullScreen();
     frame.setSize(600,500);
     frame.setVisible(true);
}

public FullScreen(){
    super("My FullscreenJFrame");

    setContentPane(contentPane);
    //From Here starts the trick

    FullScreenEffect effect = new FullScreenEffect();

    fullscreenButton.addActionListener(effect);

    contentPane.add(fullscreenButton);
    fullscreenButton.setVisible(true);

}

private class FullScreenEffect implements ActionListener{
    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

         if(Am_I_In_FullScreen == false){

                  PrevX = getX();
      PrevY = getY();
      PrevWidth = getWidth();
      PrevHeight = getHeight();

      dispose(); //Destroys the whole JFrame but keeps organized every Component                               
                  //Needed if you want to use Undecorated JFrame
                  //dispose() is the reason that this trick doesn't work with videos
                  setUndecorated(true);


 setBounds(-10,-100,getToolkit().getScreenSize().width+30,getToolkit()
.getScreenSize().height+110);
        setVisible(true);
                        Am_I_In_FullScreen = true;

          }
           else{
                setVisible(true);

                setBounds(PrevX, PrevY, PrevWidth, PrevHeight);
                dispose();
    setUndecorated(false);
    setVisible(true);
                Am_I_In_FullScreen = false;
           }
}
}
}
```